# PHP Remove any combnation of character

Tags: php, minecraft

I have a PHP class that pings a Minecraft Server, It can display the server MOTD (Message of the day). When it returns the info it uses a color character from Minecraft. The character it uses is the section sign (§). When I try to do a str replace it yeilds nothing.

```
$motd = $stats->motd;
$motd = str_replace("§1","",$motd);
$motd = str_replace("§l","",$motd);
$motd = str_replace("§4","",$motd);
echo $motd;
```

It is blank, otherwise it displays: §1§lThe Official §4§lStratHaxxs§1§l Server!
In the end I would like it to output: The Official StratHaxxs Server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem, I just made some custom code:

```
$motd = $stats->motd;
$motd = str_replace("1","",$motd);
$motd = str_replace("l","",$motd);
$motd = str_replace("4","",$motd);
$motd = str_replace("Officia","Official",$motd);
$motd = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $motd);
$motd = str_replace("TheOfficialStratHaxxsServer","The Official StratHaxxs Server",$motd);
```

Thank you brain! XD